# Worst Case Scenario Time Complexity of the add./remove operation for a bounded set using arrays?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I've tagged this as Java because I picked this quote out from 'Java Collections' - the recommended text for the course I'm doing.

So for both add/remove operations, I understand that binary search is done first and foremost to determine whether the set contains a particular element and determine where an element must be added/removed, followed by shifting if necessary.

I quote from the book which is for the add operation :

"The search stage is O(logn). The insertion stage is O(n), but is skipped if the value to be added is already a member. So the operation as a whole is O(n) in general"

Why isn't the overall time complexity O(n x logn)?

Also, if you have any other suggested texts that might be easier for the layman that you would recommend, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: O(n) + O(n) is still O(n) and not O(n^2). You execute the two things after another, not in a loop or somehow recursively. There really isn't much of a reason for a layman to deal with asymptotic complexities. But if you're curious you might as well go with TAOCP (The Art of Computer Programming) Vol 2 for how the math works - it's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because binary search is O(logn), and the Insertion stage is O(n), then the time complexity is technically O(n + logn). Because the logn is insignificant compared to n, you can just remove the logn giving the answer O(n).